# Copy file from local to hdfs with %20 in file name Python

Tags: python, hdfs

I am trying to copy 100s of Json files from local to hdfs using python subprocess.

```
subprocess.call(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-put', mylocalpath, hdfspath ])
```

This works fine if the name is proper with no special characters.

But many files have %20 as part of the file name. Sample Below.

```
File_name%201.json
```

For the above, I am getting no such file or directory error for file

```
File_name 1.json
```

%20 gets converted to spaces. As there are 100s of files I will not be able to edit it manually. Is there a way we can copy these files to hdfs using python subprocess put call.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can try to urllib.quote the file names?

Comment: The problem is my file names should not change. It should be same with %20

Comment: Not the file names on disk, the file names you pass to the copy command.